# Simplest way to check "is app running for the first time"

Tags: application-development

I am writing an app for the Ubuntu Phone and I want to store a boolean which represents if the App is running for the first time or has it run before. Personally I don't really want to create a full fledged database but if it comes to that, then sure.

Are there any simple helpers that I could call and get done ?

Comment: What I simply do sometimes is have the application create a hidden (empty?) file *if it does not exist yet*.  Depending on if it existed already, you know if the applications runs for the first time or not.

Comment: What about adding --first-run option to your app ? You could check process of that app and whether or not it runs with that flag. Helps avoid having a file

Answer (score 1):

A common way is to create a [dotfile](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hidden_file_and_hidden_directory#Unix_and_Unix-like_environments) in the user's home directory: if the file does not exist, then the program is run for the first time (or the user has requested that the program behave as if it were run for the first time, by manually deleting the file). If its sole purpose is to perform this check, the file can be empty, but usually dotfiles also serve as configuration files. For example, the Zsh shell prints this if the configuration file `~/.zshrc` does not exist when it starts:

```
This is the Z Shell configuration function for new users,
zsh-newuser-install.
You are seeing this message because you have no zsh startup files
(the files .zshenv, .zprofile, .zshrc, .zlogin in the directory
~).  This function can help you with a few settings that should
make your use of the shell easier.

You can:

(q)  Quit and do nothing.  The function will be run again next time.

(0)  Exit, creating the file ~/.zshrc containing just a comment.
     That will prevent this function being run again.

(1)  Continue to the main menu.

(2)  Populate your ~/.zshrc with the configuration recommended
     by the system administrator and exit (you will need to edit
     the file by hand, if so desired).

--- Type one of the keys in parentheses ---
```